# Why CSS !important is not working in my use case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Functionality: To change background color of disabled  from grey to white.

Opted Solution: 
I have added a class in CSS shown below:

```
.whiteBackground{
background-color: white !important; //As Pure CSS API also have rules for disabling  so i mark it as important
}
```

I have added following code in JQuery which disable select on base of :

```
$("#listOfFruits").attr('disabled',(fruitsListSize === 0)); //This fuitsListSize is returning 0 in my case, so it will be true
$('#listOfFruits').addClass((fruitsListSize === 0)?"whiteBackground":""); //listOfFruits is name of <select>
```

The above code does not work.

I have checked using Firebug and found following code of Pure CSS is getting implemented and my class is not in the list.

```
.pure-form select[disabled]{
background-color: grey (code);
cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

HTML shows my class name:

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="width:250px" name="listOfFruits" id="listOfFruits" disabled="disabled" class="whiteBackground">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code worked perfectly for me:

```
.pure-form select[disabled].whiteBackground {
background:white !important ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select[disabled]
{
background:white;
}
```

Comment: Will it not get apply on all selects?

Comment: @fatherazrael yes, add some more context to better target your select. But this is alot nicer.

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen

Thanks. But i do not want it for all selects. Let Pure CSS work on all select and on particular select i want my CSS to work.

Comment: You can make it:
`.whiteBackground[disabled]
{
 background:white;
}`

Comment: @AkshayKhetrapal
No, with above method, it is not able to Bypass Background Color given by Pure CSS classes.

Comment: Okay. Maybe it does not have more priority than Pure CSS.

Try adding parent element reference and ID reference. 

Like

`#parentElem select#listOfFruits[disabled] { background:white; }`